# Erro "Unable to resolve ILogger from Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" ao fazer um request a endpoint de azure fucntion

Tags: c#, microsoft-azure

Tenho uma azure function que tem um endpoint que questiona um repositório de dados e para ter traces do que a função faz usei o `ILogger<T>`.

A classe em causa tem a implementação no construtor

```
public class MetricsProvider
{
private readonly ILogger logger;

public MetricsProvider(ILogger<MetricsProvider> logger)
{
    this.logger = logger;
}

[FunctionName("TriggerRoseMetricsUpload")]
public async Task<IActionResult> TriggerRoseMetricsUploadAsync(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "{account}/{subscription}/TriggerRoseMetricsUpload")]HttpRequest req,
    [Queue("rose-mtr-provider", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")] ICollector<string> queue,
    string account,
    string subscription)
{
   ......
}
```

}

Quando executo tenho o erro:

**[2021-03-10T16:35:51.419Z] Executed 'TriggerRoseMetricsUpload' (Failed, Id=f95cb01e-d96e-42b9-8dcd-f330c05a425b, Duration=233ms) [2021-03-10T16:35:51.423Z] Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger`1[Primavera.Rose.AF.MTRProvider.MetricsProvider]' while attempting to activate 'Primavera.Rose.AF.MTRProvider.MetricsProvider'. [2021-03-10T16:35:51.998Z] An unhandled host error has occurred. [2021-03-10T16:35:52.000Z] Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger`1[Primavera.Rose.AF.MTRProvider.MetricsProvider]' while attempting to activate 'Primavera.Rose.AF.MTRProvider.MetricsProvider'.**

Comment: você provavelmente não registrou a dependencia a ser injetada no job startup

Comment: O que não entendo aqui, é que publicando para o azure funciona.